# How do I disable AWS SAM local in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aws-sam-cli

I installed the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse because I was working on a project that was linked with AWS Lambda. When they introduced SAM local it kept going to the top of my run configurations list, therefore running when I click the run button. I only have one AWS project and do not want this coming to the top of my list. I have checked, and I cannot see any way to disable it personally. Is it possible without uninstalling the AWS toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

Help -> Install new software -> "What is already installed" -> Select all AWS items in the installed software list -> Click uninstall and confirm restart when prompted.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the bit about "without uninstalling the AWS toolkit".

Answer (score 0):

A more appropriate solution is to just delete the AWS Lamda Plugin.

Help -> Install new software -> "What is already installed" -> Select the AWS Lamda Plugin  -> Click uninstall and confirm restart when prompted.